# Should I put a job offer from a former employer on my resume?

Tags: resume, job-offer

I had a job at a multinational company which I quit 2 years ago, it was meant to be a summer job before college. The two subsequent years, they have contacted me and offered me my position back at the company, with a considerable raise, even though they knew I was not going to be working there.

Is them making these offer resume-worthy? Specifically as a bullet that says something like "Invited back concurrent years".

On one hand it shows that I was a preferred employee, and that I did my job well. On the other, I don't really know if it's relevant.

Comment: Sounds like trying to convince them you're special because of the offer. I would put things on my resume which I actually did, this proves more in my opinion

Comment: @Houbie Isn't the whole point of a resume to convince someone you're special?

Comment: @tuskiomi Houbie was being polite.  It makes you look bad

Comment: @RichardU ah. Whoosh. they should put that in an answer.

Comment: That may be something worth mentioning during a face to face interview, at best.

Comment: I don't tend to care about what you could have done, as @Houbie says they care about what you did do

Comment: If you haven't already, you could ask your former employer for a formal recommendation letter, or to serve as a reference. That would be more useful in the job search process.

Comment: Did you at least interview for the position and turn down a real offer or was it a recruiter just calling to offer you an interview... I'm just trying to think which section would be more fun to add to my resume.

Comment: @MatthewWhited the former, well, they just straight up sent me an offer letter, after taking on the phone.

Comment: Humm... declined intereviews  (me turning down an interview), declined offers, declined promotions, and declined counter resignations... those would all be fun sections to add to a resume.  (And all would be very unprofessional)

Comment: This does seem like a somewhat silly question (no offence?) (at least to someone who's been around the block), but I'm not sure why people are voting to close it as unclear - it seems perfectly clear and valid - OP wants to put a declined offer from an ex-employer on their resume.

Comment: @Dukeling "unclear" is a catch all term for "I don't like this question" on SE.

Comment: @tuskiomi No, that's "off-topic" :) I think people were initially reacting to the question title before it was edited. I was a little confused by the original title.

Comment: Since when was putting job offers on a resume a thing?  If I saw something like this on a applicants resume I would throw the resume in the trash bin

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, you shouldn't. Your resume is supposed to reflect your work history, not declined offers or opportunities.

Answer (score 7):

No you really shouldn't do this, yes a resume is intended as a an advert for yourself but it should be limited to things you've actually done or achieved. Offers are far too ephemeral for that.

At best it will look "weird" at worst (and more likely in my opinion) it will look like you don't have enough "real" achievements and are scraping the bottom of the barrel for *something* postive to say.

Answer (score 3):

> Is them making these offer resume-worthy? Specifically as a bullet
>   that says something like "Invited back concurrent years".

No. Jobs go on resumes, not job offers.

During interviews if the discussion turns to your summer job and why you didn't subsequently work there, you can mention the offers (along with your reasons for declining them).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put this on your resume because it's impossible for any potential employer to evaluate.

Getting a job offer just says that some other person thought you had the right skills to do some other job.  That's too far removed from actual information. I don't know who that other person was, so I don't know what weight to put on their judgement about you. I don't know why that person came to that decision. Maybe it was made on the basis of a compromise that isn't relevant to me (e.g., maybe you speak the language of a major customer of that company but all my customers are domestic). Maybe they just made a bad decision.