# Should I mention that I turned down a Google offer in my resume?

Tags: resume, job-search

I've been mulling over whether I should put this sentence at the end of my resume:

> I turned down a Google offer after passing all of their interviews for family reasons

I suppose an interviewer should be happy to know it, since it shows that the candidate is skilled, has interviews experience and that handles his priority (to me having family as a priority over work is a good thing but someone might disagree about it), but on the other hand I'm not sure what kind of downsides there could be that I haven't thought of yet. The only downside I could think of, is if an employer frowned upon putting family over work (and in that case I'm not sure I'd like to work there in the first place).

Should I mention my offer rejection at all?

Comment: I wouldn't include it. It is not work experience. It could even be perceived as bragging or showing off. It adds no value whatsoever to the evaluation of your skills as a candidate for the position.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The first thing you said.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Pretty sure this is a duplicate, and pretty sure you said the exact same thing on the other question as well

Comment: @rath feel free to flag as Dupe. Besides OP could benefit from that other Q even though it were not a Dupe, so consider sharing it anyways.

Comment: I don't think this count as an answer, but if in an interview they ask you if you are interviewing/have offers anywhere else you could tell that story. That could give a good impression since they asked specifically about it

Comment: @Homerothompson you could actually work that into a good answer.

Comment: Similar question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/91383/is-it-appropriate-to-include-declined-post-doc-offers-on-your-cv

Comment: Similar: [Should I put a job offer from a former employer on my resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96333)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere stating you received a job offer from Google is not the same as stating you have never worked for Google. There are plenty of merits one could include on a CV/resume which isn't directly work experience for a company. I wouldn't suggest OP includes this, but not for the reasoning that they never worked at Google. If I asked "Should I include an award nomination for a competition held by Google?" you would not respond with "No because you have never worked at Google" would you?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Ok, so the reason to not include it is because it can't be verified, not because he never worked for Google. That was my point.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Don't include it.**

This is just a claim that (whether true or not) the company has no way of verifying. You could say that you turned down an offer for a director position at Apple, or VP at Wells Fargo, or TIME Magazine's Person of the Year - there's nothing stopping you from lying, so your statement can't be believed at face value.

Obviously there's nothing stopping you from making up other parts of your resume too, but your education, work history, and skill set can all be independently verified by the company to which you are applying. I highly doubt that Google would tell a hiring manager from a different company that *"Yes, we offered TesterPen a position as code ninja, but they turned us down."*

At best, including it will be ignored. At worst, it will look like you're making things up. Don't do it.

Comment: Agree with this. It's not resume material. One should include work experiences, knowledge, certifications, etc. Not something that "you say that you did"... If I were hiring, knowing that you turned down that position would add nothing to the evaluation of your skills and if you are a fit to this company, so basically it's just noise in your resume.

Comment: @DarkCygnus - Don't think OP is asking if it should be in their resume, but whether they should mention it in pre-screens or actual interviews.  Doesn't actually change the ultimate answer, "no," but it sounds like you were thinking "resume," which was my initial assumption, as well.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Resume is in the question title

Comment: @DavidK - right you are!

Answer (score 4):

I would only mention that if you are asked in an interview about you going to other interviews or having other offers. That way since you are answering a direct question you won't sound like bragging and could give the perception that you are a good/wanted candidate.

Comment: Yes, this should only be brought during an interview when asked, where it could actually help (whereas on the resume it would be just noise).

Answer (score -3):

Firstly, if you were to put it somewhere, you need to make sure the most important bit is at the front. Currently that is ''I turned down a Google offer'', which seems a funny thing to be proud of. I think you probably want to say something closer to ''I have received a job offer from Google that I was unable to accept because the timing was not right''.

Secondly, if you are going to put it somewhere, it should probably not be in your resume. I think it would not be so bad to put in your cover letter though. You may want to think about asking one of the people interviewing you at Google to give you a reference to back up your claim.